# Removing spaces and compare two strings

Tags: sql

I want to compare 2 tables and see if the value of one of their columns is identical. Here is the code that wrote:

```
    select T1.TaskCMPLTDetails,T2.TaskCMPLTDetails, T1.RequestID,T2.RequestID, t1.ProtocolID,t2.ProtocolID, t1.BuildCMPLTDT, t2.BuildCMPLTDT
    From table as T1 inner join table as T2
    on  T1.ProtocolID  = T2.ProtocolID 
    where REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(T1.TaskCMPLTDetails)), '  ', ' ') <> REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(T2.TaskCMPLTDetails)), '  ', ' ') 
    and t1.BuildCMPLTDT=t2.BuildCMPLTDT
```

And, here is the results that I got back; (copied only a row):

```
Y,Val,2017,1158,    Y, Val, 2017, 1158,   2017  2017    1158    1158    1900-01-01  1900-01-01
```

As you can see in the result, TaskCMPLTDetails is the same for the both tables, why do I see this? The code supposed to return the results that donot have an identical TaskCMPLTDetails!!

Comment: Why replace two white spaces with one?  If you don't want the white space, replace each single whitespace with an empty string like this `REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(T1.TaskCMPLTDetails)), ' ', '')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this statement:

```
REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(T1.TaskCMPLTDetails)), '  ', ' ')
```

you replace every 2 adjacent spaces with 1 space. 
So when your column's value has 3 spaces in it like this:

```
'A   B' (3 spaces)
```

the result will be:

```
'A  B'  (2 spaces)
```

because in the initial value only 2 adjacent spaces were replaced by 1 space, 
so this result contains also 2 adjacent spaces.
The `REPLACE` function acts only once and not recursively so to replace again and again until there are not any 2 adjacent spaces. 
The solution to your problem would be to **remove all spaces** from both columns before comparing them, because the columns contain comma separated values so there will be no unwanted joining of values in this case (or so it seems from the sample data you posted):

```
where REPLACE(T1.TaskCMPLTDetails, ' ', '') <> REPLACE(T2.TaskCMPLTDetails, ' ', '')
```

Comment: This is undoubtedly the right thing to do...but what a mess the OP has to solve. The column was somebody's bad idea of something "easy to use" that morphed into un-indexable sludge. From the output row, t's clear that it duplicates some of the other column values. So, I'd only add that, if there are indexes on the "other columns", then I'd include those in the join conditions as well...so as to limit the number of replacements that have to be performed. My heart goes out to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple trim()   TRIM(T1.TaskCMPLTDetails) <> TRIM(T2.TaskCMPLTDetails)

```
    select T1.TaskCMPLTDetails
      ,T2.TaskCMPLTDetails
      , T1.RequestID
      ,T2.RequestID
      , t1.ProtocolID
      ,t2.ProtocolID
      , t1.BuildCMPLTDT
      , t2.BuildCMPLTDT
    From table as T1 
    inner join table as T2  on  T1.ProtocolID  = T2.ProtocolID 
    where  TRIM(T1.TaskCMPLTDetails) <> TRIM(T2.TaskCMPLTDetails)
    and t1.BuildCMPLTDT=t2.BuildCMPLTDT
```